# How to get the first element of a matching line in TCL

Tags: tcl

I have a line in a file as shown below:

```
Start Test
     111111 total failures seen.
End Test
```

I want to get the 111111 in a variable in TCL. The 111111 number is variable and can be any number of digits. How can I do this? I tried this but it is returning the full line except the number and I want the number.

```
regexp {\s+[0-9]total failures seen} $line a
```

Answer (score 3):

Use parentheses to store the substring you want to match (the numbers) in a second match variable, `num`:

```
regexp {\s+([0-9]+) total failures seen} $line a num
```

Note the slightly different expression which matches a string with *one or more digits*, followed by a space before the next word.